# Injecting custom batches of a Tank

Tags: anylogic

I have my own batch objects flowing into a tank. Now, based on some logic, I would like to create some batches at the output different than the input ones. For example, assume my tank is empty, and say I have batch A (volume 5000.0) flowing in the tank, followed by batch B (volume 6000.0). Then, when 5000.0 of B is landed in the tank, I would like to create a batch C with volume 10000.0 and let it flow out of the tank.

I do not think that ***Output batch*** for the tank can do this. It has to be a more complicated logic. My idea is to dispense the 10000.0 on one hand from the tank, reinject the 10000.0 with a fluidSource while synchronizing the dispense/reinject rate. Any other approach?

[image]

Comment: the output batch can definitely do exactly what you want to do... I don't see the problem you are having

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted in a different way. Trying again to use the output batch for tank. Essentially, I would like the same functionality as the function fluidSource.inject(...). I cannot see how I can do that with output batch. Would you have a snippet of code (updated my comment above)

Comment: you can't inject to a tank... you can use a fluidSource as a tank if you need that.. and the output batch can be any object: uniform(), "batch", 4834, agent, etc... it's up to you

Comment: Understood, but what would the volume associated to this custom output batch? This is what is not clear to me. fluidSource.inject(...) associates a volume to your object, which I agree could be anything

Comment: if you are using a tank, what comes out comes out with a certain rate.. you can define the volume that comes out with a valve for instance...